# Trying to create 3 specifically laid out divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some specific divs to hold content and I'm stuck trying to just create them using colors.
I went ahead and uploaded a crude idea of what I'm trying to create so I could show you guys.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCVp5.jpg
I can get the first large square to show but not the other ones, can anyone shed some insight?

```css
#row-one {
 padding-top: 1em;
}
#left-block {
 float: left;
 width: 45%;
 height: 25em;
 background-color: black;
}
#right-block {
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}
#block-one {
 width: 100%;
 height: 12em
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="row-one">
  <div id="left-block">
   <!--PLACEHOLDER-->
  </div>
  <div id="right block">
   <div id="block-one"></div>
   <div id="block-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` in `height: 12em background-color: black;` which causes the height and background color to not be interpreted. You also have no CSS for #block-two

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realize the missing ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the semicolon `;` after `height: 12em` and there were no styles specified for `#block-two`. Also, you specified the styles for the `right-block` div but were also missing the `-` in `<div id="right block">`.

```css
#row-one {
 padding-top: 1em;
}
#left-block {
 float: left;
 width: 45%;
 height: 25em;
 background-color: black;
}
#right-block {
 float: right;
 width: 45%;
}
#block-one, #block-two {
 width: 100%;
 height: 12em;
 background-color: black;
 vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row-one">
  <div id="left-block">
   <!--PLACEHOLDER-->
  </div>
  <div id="right-block">
   <div id="block-one"></div>
   <div id="block-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I said in my comment five minutes ago.

Comment: The `-` between `<div id="right block">` was also missing.

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't put anything for the second block because I couldn't get the first one to work. Thank you for the revised code.